# React app with firebase function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, create-react-app

I am quite new to nodejs and firebase and I created a simple to-do list kind of app using create-react-app with firebase.

This application has a text field to save message to firebase real time database and display all the submitted message on the same page too.

Everything was fine and I am able to host it in firebase but now I am having problem to generate a "session id" from firebase function and store in the "__session" cookie.

I know that my "build" folder that deploy to firebase hosting can not have any index.html in order to trigger the firebase function with the firebase hosting URL.
So I think of delete the index.html from the "build" folder and return the entire HTML from the firebase function but then I saw a lot of people not recommend to do this way.

I am quite stuck now and no idea what is a better way of doing this.

Hope my question are clear.

Thanks!

Comment: why do you need to store a session when firebase does this for you automatically?